# Conditional spacing while alert is present

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I am working on an app and the way they have it set up is that they want the alert to be displayed under fixed headers of a table. The problem is, when the alert is present, the margin from the unfixed table rows below is present under the alert box which causes a mess of space in between the alert and the table data as seen below.

[image]

I have an idea where I would set the alert to fixed or absolute and add a div beneath it with the proper amount of margin that would only be present when the alert is present. Using ng-if, how would I be able to show this new div only if the alert is present? Can I target both the "close" or the "dismiss-on-timeout"? This is how the alert is set up:

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="AlertCtrl" class="alertControl">
    <alert class="ngAlert" ng-repeat="alert in alerts" type="{{alert.type}}" close="closeAlert($index)" dismiss-on-timeout="7000">{{alert.msg}}</alert>
</div>
<div class="alertSpacing" ng-if=""></div>
```

CSS:

```
.alertSpacing {
    height: 100px; //The proper amount of spacing between the fixed headings and the bottom of the alert
    width: 100%;
}
```

The alert spacing div is the one that I only need present when the alert is active.

Thank you for any help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try giving `clear: both` to the class:

```
.alertSpacing {
  clear: both;
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. This is not the issue. The issue is that the alertSpacing div must only be present when the alert is present in the DOM. Do you have any advice for how to approach this?

Comment: The CSS gets applied only when the div is in place.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ng-class` directive on the table to set a class that has the margin value whether the alert is shown or not.

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="AlertCtrl" class="alertControl">
    <alert class="ngAlert" ng-repeat="alert in alerts" type="{{alert.type}}" close="closeAlert($index)" dismiss-on-timeout="7000">{{alert.msg}}</alert>
</div>

<table ng-class="{'table-margin-top': alerts.length == 0}">
    ...
</table>
```

CSS:

```
table {
    margin-top: 100px;
}

.table-margin-top {
    margin-top: 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks so much for the response. This is definitely a good start, but the issue now is, alerts.length does not evaluate to 0 thus the class is never active

Comment: Can you post some of your Directive code where you are setting / adding the alerts so I can help further?